# SharePoint SE - cluttered interface, how to deal with it?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are about to upgrade from SharePoint 2016 Server to SharePoint Subscription Edition and the (not so) new modern experience. First impressions, I'm confused. It's so apart. Old lists and new lists mixed depending what type of list you are creating. Our existing pages will be left in classic style, while a new page will be created using modern UI (still not modern like online modern but som limited on premise modern type of page). Powershell is not our friend here ether since on premise pages can't be transformed using script (not supported).

Navigating through our site will be an utterly messed up experience! It's half done, modern transition stopped in the middle.

What's your experience going from classic SharePoint to modern (server-based)? How do we keep a solid and user friendly experience using SharePoint SE? Is there a way to avoid this cluttered interface, like remove all classic list templates from beeing used? Is that even possible?

SharePoint Online is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a plan for adopting the modern experience for all your SharePoint content.

For lists and libraries, this isn't so bad as you can simply switch the experience in list/library settings.

As you are on-premises, unless you want to build your own automated methods using PowerShell or CSOM etc, you may need to manually create the new modern pages and begin copying information across from the classic pages. Though, this may be an opportunity to improve your intranet content and take advantage of modern web parts.

Personally, I have found the modern experience to be a massive improvement for user experience. The key is that you do not want a hybrid of classic and modern experience, since this will make things very confusing for users.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I definitely prefer the modern UI. But how do I prevent people from using all those classic list templates that still exists under "Add a program"?

Comment: Hope this article may help you:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover this.

Comment: Still, if I create a calendar in SharePoint SE it will be classic and there is no way it can be converted to modern (since there is no modern calendar in SPSE). Is there a way to disable or delete all classic list templates in SPSE?

Comment: The user shouldn't be able to create the classic calendar, as they'll be using the modern site contents view. Hopefully the modern calendar will be released to SharePoint SE soon.

Comment: Unfortunately you can select and create list types like calendars even if the web site itself is in modern state, that's the problem. :(

Comment: Is it just calendars? That might make sense since there is no modern equivalent in SharePoint SE. Other lists and libraries should default to modern experience or can be set to modern via list settings.

Comment: No, there's still a bunch of classic templates in a modern site like tasks, discussions, wiki's and more. Referencing to this page /_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx

Comment: Does this appear in the modern site contents page? Doesn't the new drop down give a much smaller list of options? That's the classic "Add an app" page you're referring to? Users would be going to the modern site contents page surely

Comment: Yes, exactly, even in a modern team site, "Add an app" goes to this old addanapp.aspx page with old templates. Some templates do create modern lists, like the custom list template. Others creates old lists using classic UI. "Add an app" in SPO goes to appStore.aspx with modern apps only.